# Trying to scrape data off of website but continuously get errors

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

Ok so essentially what I'm trying to do is iterate through each team that has made the NCAA Men's basketball tournament in the past 6 years and scrape their roster off of [this website](https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Mountain-West-Conference/6/Nevada/345/stats/2018/Averages/All/All/Season/All/points/desc/1/). Here is my code:

```
for (i in c(1:length(team_performance$Team))){
  burner_mpg_link <- getURL(paste("https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/",gsub(team_performance$Conference[i]," ","-"),
  "/16/",gsub(team_performance$Team[i]," ","-"),"/",team_performance$Number[i],"/stats/",team_performance$Year[i],
  "/Averages/All/All/Season/All/minutes/desc/1/",sep = ""))

  webpage <- read_html(burner_mpg_link)

  tables <- readHTMLTable(burner_mpg_link)
  table1 <- html_table(tables[1], fill = TRUE)
  data.frame(table1)

  temp_data$NULL.Year <- NULL
  temp_data$NULL.Year <- x

  mpg_data <- rbind(mpg_data,temp_data)

  percent_complete <- (100/384)*i
  print(paste(round(percent_complete,digits = 2),"% complete",sep=""))
}
```

team_performance is a data frame that, at this point in the program, contains team name, year, seed in the tournament, rounds advanced, conference, and the number in the url for the website that corresponds to that team. My issue is that `table1 <- html_table(tables[1], fill = TRUE)` tells me that `html_table` doesn't work because `tables[1]` is a list. Ok, I get that. Then, when I try to use `unlist` to unlist `tables[1]`, it gives `Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) 'names' attribute [345] must be the same length as the vector [23]`. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Edit: Repeatable example.

```
> head(team_performance)
                 Team Year Seed Rounds.Advanced              Conference Number
1               Akron 2013   12               1 Mid-American Conference    174
2             Alabama 2012    9               1 Southeastern Conference    253
3              Albany 2015   14               1 America East Conference      6
4              Albany 2014   16               1 America East Conference      6
5              Albany 2013   15               1 America East Conference      6
6 American University 2014   15               1         Patriot League     245
```

I want the scraped data to be the player stats table on [the given website](https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Mountain-West-Conference/6/Nevada/345/stats/2018/Averages/All/All/Season/All/points/desc/1/) in a data frame.

Edit 2:

```
> dput(head(team_performance))
structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Akron", 
"Alabama", "Albany", "American University", "Arizona", "Arizona State", 
"Arkansas", "Austin Peay", "Baylor", "Belmont", "Brigham Young", 
"Bucknell", "Buffalo", "Butler", "Cal Poly", "Cal State Bakersfield", 
"California", "Chattanooga", "Cincinnati", "Coastal Carolina", 
"Colorado", "Colorado State", "Connecticut", "Creighton", "Davidson", 
"Dayton", "Delaware", "Detroit-Mercy", "Duke", "East Tennessee State", 
"Eastern Kentucky", "Eastern Washington", "Florida", "Florida Gulf Coast", 
"Florida State", "Fresno State", "George Washington", "Georgetown", 
"Georgia", "Georgia State", "Gonzaga", "Green Bay", "Hampton", 
"Harvard", "Hawaii", "Holy Cross", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iona", 
"Iowa", "Iowa State", "Jacksonville State", "James Madison", 
"Kansas", "Kansas State", "Kent State", "Kentucky", "La Salle", 
"Lafayette", "Lehigh", "Little Rock", "Long Beach State", "Long Island", 
"Louisville", "Loyola (MD)", "LSU", "Manhattan", "Marquette", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Memphis", "Mercer", "Miami (FL)", 
"Michigan", "Michigan State", "Middle Tennessee State", "Milwaukee", 
"Minnesota", "Missouri", "Montana", "Mount St. Mary's", "Murray State", 
"NC State", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Mexico", "New Mexico State", 
"Norfolk State", "North Carolina", "North Carolina A&T", "North Carolina Central", 
"North Dakota", "North Dakota State", "Northeastern", "Northern Iowa", 
"Northern Kentucky", "Northwestern", "Northwestern State", "Notre Dame", 
"Ohio", "Ohio State", "Oklahoma", "Oklahoma State", "Ole Miss", 
"Oregon", "Oregon State", "Pacific", "Pittsburgh", "Princeton", 
"Providence", "Purdue", "Rhode Island", "Robert Morris", "Saint Joseph's", 
"Saint Louis", "Saint Mary's", "San Diego State", "Seton Hall", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota State", "South Florida", "Southern", 
"Southern Methodist", "Southern Mississippi", "St. Bonaventure", 
"St. John's", "Stanford", "Stephen F. Austin", "Stony Brook", 
"Syracuse", "Temple", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Texas A&M", "Texas Southern", 
"Texas Tech", "Troy", "Tulsa", "UAB", "UC Davis", "UC Irvine", 
"UCLA", "UNC Asheville", "UNC Wilmington", "UNLV", "USC", "Utah", 
"Valparaiso", "Vanderbilt", "VCU", "Vermont", "Villanova", "Virginia", 
"Virginia Tech", "Weber State", "West Virginia", "Western Kentucky", 
"Western Michigan", "Wichita State", "Winthrop", "Wisconsin", 
"Wofford", "Wyoming", "Xavier", "Yale"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2013L, 
2012L, 2015L, 2014L, 2013L, 2014L), Seed = c(12L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 
15L, 15L), Rounds.Advanced = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Conference = structure(c(17L, 
25L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L), .Label = c("America East Conference", 
"American Athletic Conference", "Atlantic 10 Conference", "Atlantic Coast Conference", 
"Atlantic Sun Conference", "Big 12 Conference", "Big East Conference", 
"Big Sky Conference", "Big South Conference", "Big Ten Conference", 
"Big West Conference", "Colonial Athletic Association ", "ConferenceUSA ", 
"Horizon League ", "Ivy League ", "Metro Atlantic Athletic Conference", 
"Mid-American Conference", "Mid-Eastern Athletic Conference", 
"Missouri Valley Conference", "Mountain West Conference", "Northeast Conference", 
"Ohio Valley Conference", "Pacific-12 Conference", "Patriot League ", 
"Southeastern Conference", "Southern Conference", "Southland Conference", 
"Southwestern Athletic Conference", "Sun Belt Conference", "The Summit League ", 
"West Coast Conference", "Western Athletic Conference"), class = "factor"), 
Number = c(174L, 253L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 245L)), .Names = c("Team", 
"Year", "Seed", "Rounds.Advanced", "Conference", "Number"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ok so the url needs to be pasted in exactly that order. If you look at this url: 

    https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Mountain-West-Conference/6/Nevada/345/stats/2018/Averages/All/All/Season/All/points/desc/1/

The conference (Mountain West Conference), school (Nevada), school number (345), and year (2018) need to be the ones that change. It should paste together to become a url like this one but leading you to each team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `dat=team_performance` You can do the following:

```
library(rvest)
s=gsub("\\s","-",paste0("https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/",dat[,5],"/16/",
                      dat[,1],"/",dat[,6],"/stats/",dat[,2],
                      "/Averages/All/All/Season/All/minutes/desc/1/"))


A=lapply(s,function(x){
  read_html(x)%>%html_nodes("table")%>%html_table()
})
```

Comment: These are different sites. Do you want to put all the data into one dataframe?

Comment: Preferably yes and label each with team and year columns

Comment: What if we make each site a dataframe, add the team and year columns, then rbind them together?

Comment: gsub, greedily substitutes any space within the pasted string with a "-

Comment: Ok so `//s` is the same as a space

Comment: \\s is the same as sace

Comment: You cannot put them in one dataframe. The tables have varying number of columns

Comment: Oh true. So first separate the tables from each other and delete the second two. Would we subset the list?

Comment: If you want to delete the second two and put the rest in a dataframe `do.call(rbind,lapply(yourlist,"[[",1))`

Comment: I did/\. Gives this: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds